# sqlite date query not working as expected after importing db from CSV

Tags: sqlite

I imported a CSV file into sqlite db.
Date query in my simple sqlite db seems to give wrong results.

I have some dates ranging from year 2017 to 2021.

But a query for date less than `date("2020-01-01")` returns all the records

```
sqlite> select count(*) from telemetry ;
29729
sqlite> select count(*) from telemetry where dt < date("2020-01-01") ;
29729
sqlite> select who, msg, dt, typeof(dt), ts from telemetry limit 3 ;
who   |msg                | dt       |typeof(dt)| ts
=====================================================================
eng120| Endpoint initialized| 2017-09-07|text| 1504778578
eng120| Client initialized| 2017-09-07|text| 1504778578
NOHOST| Client initialized| 2021-03-15|text| 1615817190
```

Comment: Post the column headers also in the results of `select * from telemetry limit 3;`

Comment: Added column headers to the query results

Comment: What about the results of `select typeof(dt) from telemetry limit 3;`?

Comment: Updated query to list `typeof(dt)`

Comment: Check for leading spaces in `dt`: `where trim(dt) < date("2020-01-01")`

Comment: wow.. that precisely was the problem. Thanks @forpas

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by spaces around the date field in my DB.
The CVS file that I imported into DB contained spaces.
Trimming the spaces resolved this issue.

Thanks @Forpas for pointing this out